# Conversion Process From Single-Ended to a Differential Filter

Tags: filter

I have a single ended filter which is quite similar to the one on the following picture;

[image: filter]

My question is how to convert from single ended to a differential filter. Especially the inductors and capacitors which are going to the ground? 
Should one multiply or divide its values? or ?

Thanks/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, just draw a line across all of the grounds and then mirror the entire circuit over the line.  See: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slwa053b/slwa053b.pdf

After that, you can remove the ground connections and combine series components (two caps in series become one of 1/2 the value, two inductors in series combine to one 2x the value, etc.)

You should end up with your line of inductors duplicated at the bottom with the same values, interconnected by series LC circuits with 1/2C and 2L.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me. and thanks for the link as well

Comment: @yaya, so why no +1?  (I'll add it for you.)

Comment: it says; vote up requires 15 reputations :(